# How to get ":name" from "path"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I have this.
How to get ":name" from "path" as param and give this to field "somefield" of  BlogPage component?

```
<Route 
   path = "/blog/:name" 
   element={
      <BlogPage
         {// how to do this?}
         somefield = ? 
      />
   }
/>
```

Comment: I solved this problem with "window.location.href"

Answer (score 1):

In your `<BlogPage />` component add the following

```
    const { name } = useParams();`
```

Answer (score 0):

`Route` has the `component` property, where you can inject your component.

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/blog/:name" component={BlogPage} />
</Router>
```

In your `BlogPage` component, you can access the parameters like this:

```
function BlogPage(props) {
  return <h1>Hello {props.match.params.name}!</h1>
}
```

Check [this](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) to get more information.